# Linking tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

**Table1**

```
ID
Language
```

**Table2**

```
ID
LanguageValue
```

`ID` columns in both tables are PKs, Now if I want Table 1's `Language` column to fetch data from Table 2's `LanguageValue` column, how do I link them? FKs are used when columns got PK or Unique constraint on them so I am confused now. Plz help..thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial for setting up triggers.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

With triggers, you can say when something is inserted, updated, or deleted on Table1, do something to Table2. Bit to learn, but it's one way to do it.

Comment: so when new record is added in LanguageValue column of Table2 then this will add that record in Table1's Language column automatically ? right ? sry confused coz I am new to mssql

Comment: ooooo, you want the values replicated. what you want is a trigger. one sec.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what "Language" and "LanguageValue" might be?  I'm confused as to what you're trying to store.

Comment: the values in both table's columns will be en-EN, fr-FR, etc

Comment: OK so the data in Table1 and Table2 will be identical?  Then yes, you want a trigger and should take a look at seekerOfKnowledge's link.

Comment: @charliegriefer +1 for obvious reasons.